# web form field data not passing to php

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm learning, trying to create a simple web form, validate the form data, and pass the data to a php file.

After all of the field values are validated, they are not being passed to the php file.

```
<form action="/xxxxx.php" method="post" name="registration" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
```

I've change the form name to anything else...

```
<form action="/xxxxx.php" method="post" name="anythingelse" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
```

...the form works (without validation) and the field values are being passed to the php file. I'm receiving the completed form, so I know without validation the web form is working correctly.

So it would appear as though there is something wrong with the validation, I.E. the function(s) are returning false even after all functions have passed validation and presumably returned true.

Or something else is wrong. I don't understand what's wrong? I'd appreciate any help.

Here's the code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formValidation() {
            var uname = document.registration.username;
            var uadd = document.registration.city;
            var ucountry = document.registration.country;
            var uzip = document.registration.zip;
            var uemail = document.registration.email;
            var uphone = document.registration.phone;
            {
                if (allLetter(uname)) {
                    if (alphanumeric(uadd)) {
                        if (countryselect(ucountry)) {
                            if (allnumeric(uzip)) {
                                if (ValidateEmail(uemail)) {
                                    if (validatePhone(uphone)) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;

        }

        function validatePhone(uphone) {
            var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$/;
            if (uphone.value.match(letters)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('Phone Number [Required]: Please enter your phone number (use this format, xxx-xxx-xxxx)');
                uphone.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
        function allLetter(uname) {
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
            if (uname.value.match(letters)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('Full Name [Required]: Please enter your full name (alphabet characters only)');
                uname.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
        function alphanumeric(uadd) {
            var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$/;
            if (uadd.value.match(letters)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('City [Required]: Please enter your city (alphabet characters only)');
                uadd.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
        function countryselect(ucountry) {
            if (ucountry.value == "Default") {
                alert('State [Required]: Please select your State from the drop down list');
                ucountry.focus();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        function allnumeric(uzip) {
            var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
            if (uzip.value.match(numbers)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('ZIP code [Required]: Please enter your Zip Code (numbers only, use this format xxxxx)');
                uzip.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
        function ValidateEmail(uemail) {
            var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
            if (uemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('Email Address [Required]: You have entered an invalid email address. Please verify and correct your email address.');
                uemail.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>
    <form name="registration" action="/xxxxxx.php" method="post" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="xxxxx - Contact" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="confirmation.html" />
    <div>
        <strong>Email Address [Required]:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="email" size="50" title="Please enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><strong>Company Name [Optional]:</strong></span> <span>
            <input type="text" id="companyName" name="companyName" size="50" title="Please enter your company name" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><strong>Full Name:</strong></span> <span>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="30" title="Please enter your full name" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><strong>Phone Number:</strong></span> <span>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" size="17" title="Please enter your phone number" /></span>
        <br />
        <span><strong>Phone Ext. [Optional]:</strong></span> <span>
            <input type="text" id="phoneExtn" name="phoneExtn" size="10" title="Please enter your phone extension" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><strong>City:</strong></span> <span>
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="25" title="Please enter your city" /></span>
        <span><strong>State:</strong></span> <span>
            <select id="country" name="country" title="Please select your state from the drop down list">
                <option selected="" value="Default">Select a State</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="GU">Guam</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dokota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VI">Virgin Islands</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><strong>Zip Code:</strong></span> <span>
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" size="10" title="Please enter your zip code" /></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="qsadditionalRequirementsQuestion">
        <strong>Briefly describe your purpose for contacting us today:</strong>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea name="PurposeForContact" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please format your code it is unsightly.

Comment: If you skip validation, does it work?

Comment: return true inside your inner most `if` condition for validation?

Comment: if I skip validation it does work

Comment: Sorry to say, I'm not sure where the inner most if condition is.

Comment: {
}
}
}
} 
}
}
}
return false;

Comment: if I change that to true, the validation stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main `if` statements are contained within random opening and closing braces.

Try removing those random braces, adding `return true;` inside of your last nested `if` statement, and containing the `return false;` within an `elseif` after the closing braces of the `if` statements

EDIT:

```
if (allLetter(uname)) {
    if (alphanumeric(uadd)) {
       if (countryselect(ucountry)) {
        if (allnumeric(uzip)) {
            if (ValidateEmail(uemail)) {
                if (validatePhone(uphone)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
else {
return false;
}
```

There are much, much better ways of doing this, but without changing what you've already got too much, try the above.

Comment: if I remove the seven random braces the validation does not work

Comment: Not all 7, just the one before the first `if` statement, after the last variable declaration, and the closing brace for that

Comment: I removed the brace before the first if statement and the first closing brace after after the last  leaving 6 closing braces before return false. The validation works but it is not passing the data to the php

Comment: function formValidation() 
    {
    var uname = document.registration.username;
    var uadd = document.registration.city;
    var ucountry = document.registration.country;
    var uzip = document.registration.zip;
    var uemail = document.registration.email;
    var uphone = document.registration.phone;

    if(allLetter(uname))
    {
    if(alphanumeric(uadd))
    { 
    if(countryselect(ucountry))
    {
    if(allnumeric(uzip))
    {
    if(ValidateEmail(uemail))
    {
    if(validatePhone(uphone))
    {

    }
    }
    } 
    }
    }
    }
    return false;

Comment: Now add the `return true;` and the `elseif` around the `return false;`

Comment: In fact, you would need a `return false;` after every `if` statement, not just the last one

Comment: is this the right syntax?

return true;
}
else if return false;

Comment: are yo saying I would have to add

return true
}
else return false
}
 after each of the main if statements

Comment: My mistake, I meant `else` not `elseif`, see the edit in my actual answer

Comment: Callan - don't know how to thank you for your help. I do appreciate it. This worked.
I will look it over all over, now that it works, to discover why my original code did not work to begin with.

How do I handle the finish? Just click the edit on your post?
Anything else I can do?